# JavaScript Dependency Injection + jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, scope

I've been looking to refresh my Backbone skills as an upcoming job will be using it (I usually work in Angular or on the back-end).  I was looking through todomvc's Backbone example and came across this.  I'm wondering why the $ is passed into the closure / anonymous function.  If it was dependency injection I would expect underscore to be passed in too.  I notced the $ isn't passed in any other files / closures.  [Github source](https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/blob/gh-pages/architecture-examples/backbone/js/views/app-view.js)

```
/*global Backbone, jQuery, _, ENTER_KEY */
var app = app || {};

(function ($) {
    'use strict';

    // The Application
    // ---------------

    // Our overall **AppView** is the top-level piece of UI.
    app.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
```

Comment: Can you paste the entire function? I think, at the end of the function you will have something like })(jQuery). If so, you are passing jQuery object into the self executing function to be scoped locally using the variable $.

Comment: @Jebin That's correct, but I don't see the benefit of scoping jQuery locally when it's already available in the global scope.  The other thing is, why just jQuery.  They're also using underscore here, why not scope `_` locally as well?  Also, the entire file is available in the Github source link in my post.

Edit: Found the answer to that second question here: http://gregfranko.com/blog/i-love-my-iife/

Thanks for the info, if you submit it as an answer I'll select it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of this code is to provide "modularity", privacy and encapsulation for your code.

It is a kind of alias that you are making for jQuery inside the self executing function. 
The purpose of passing jQuery in to the parenthesis is to provide local scoping to the global variable. This helps reduce the amount of overhead of looking up the $ variable, and allows better compression / optimization for minifiers in some cases.

Sending in $ as an argument to an anonymous function makes $ local to that function which has a small positive performance implication if the $ function is called a lot. This is because javascript searches the local scope for variables first and then traverses down all the way to the window scope (where $ usually lives).

Also it is to avoid a potential conflict of the $ variable. If something else defines a variable named $, your plugin may use the wrong definition